# need to know how to remove duplicate rows from SQL to fetch data from a variety of tables;

Tags: sql-server

I need data from a variety of tables and below is the only way I know to do it (I just know the basics). The query below works fine but shows duplicates. I need to know how to remove those.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    a.int_order_id, a.trans_id, a.wtn,a.isp_id,
    d.first_name, d.middle_initial, d.last_name,
    d.company_name, d.emaiL,
    a.ilec_lob, a.node_type_id, a.cddd,
    a.isp_ban, a.tos_version, a.isp_ckt_id,
    a.isp_circuit_type, a.atm_vpi, a.atm_vci, 
    a.frs_dlci, b.order_create_date, b.pon,
    b.order_status_id, e.trans_status_id,
    e.description, c.STREET_NUMBER, 
    c.STREET_NUMBER_SUFFIX, c.DIRECTIONAL_ID,
    c.street_name, c.thoroughfare_id, 
    c.street_suffix, c.address_line1, c.address_line2,
    c.unit_type_id, c.unit_value, c.city, c.state_id, c.zip 
FROM 
    VZEXTRACT1.vvov_os_ord_dsl A 
JOIN 
    VZEXTRACT1.vvov_os_order_details B ON a.int_order_id = b.int_order_id 
JOIN 
    VZEXTRACT1.vvov_os_ord_address C ON b.int_order_id = c.int_order_id 
JOIN 
    vzextract1.vvov_os_ord_contact D ON c.int_order_id = d.int_order_id 
JOIN 
    VZEXTRACT1.vv0v_trans_status E On b.order_status_id = e.trans_status_id 
WHERE 
    a.isp_id NOT IN (657,500) 
    AND B.ORDER_CREATE_DATE >= to_date('01-may-15') 
    AND B.ORDER_CREATE_DATE < to_date('30-JUL-15')
```

Comment: Please mention how you know the result is duplicate? Is it the complete row? If it is on the basis of a set of columns then which result you want to keep and which one to delete!

Comment: The result is a complete row. I want to keep row where data is not null for the following columns: c.STREET_NUMBER, 
    c.STREET_NUMBER_SUFFIX, c.DIRECTIONAL_ID,
    c.street_name, c.thoroughfare_id, 
    c.street_suffix, c.address_line1, c.address_line2,
    c.unit_type_id, c.unit_value, c.city, c.state_id, c.zip

Comment: How to determine which result is duplicate? The nulls is another unrelated filter or is it related to duplicate somehow. Can you please clarify what exactly is the issue? You can tell us input and expected output.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to remove duplicate rows you will have to use

1. Distinct : It will consider distinct of all selected columns so you will have to find out because of which column you are getting duplicate rows even if you have used distinct
2. Group by : You can use group by clause to get distinct rows. You can use aggregate function for column causing duplicate rows from point 1 and avoid duplicates.
3. over(partition by) : you can also use this clause for column causing duplicates. Like you concat values of such column ,
   wm_concat(my_col)over(partition by id)